# extjs submit tabpanel under formpanel?

Tags: extjs, struts2, tabpanel, formpanel

layout:window-->tabpanel-->formpanel.
if i want submit formpanel,but have a lot formpanel,
i don't know how to do!
is layout problem ? 
i'm java programmer.i use struts2+extjs...

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by this. Do you have a form with several tabs? Do you want to submit all these tabs at once or do you want to submit each tab separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use multiple form panels.

Use:

```
new Ext.Window({
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            items: {
                title: 'Tab 1',
                layout: 'form'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

After that, you only submit the one main form.

Comment: you know i mean.
my layout:tab-->form(
  layout:'form',
  items:[{
 layout:'column',       
 items:[{
  columnWidth : .3,   
  layout:'form',     
  items:[{
   xtype:'hidden',
   name:'id'
                 }]
            }]
      }]
)